# What's the difference between a daemon listening on 10.0.2.15:53 and a daemon listening on 0.0.0.0:53?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, port, daemon

I wanted to know the difference between these two states, I just did a netstat -anob on my 2008 R2 testing machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One is listening to a specific IP address (interface) while the 0.0.0.0 is listening to all interfaces (loopback, a local address, public address...any address the machine has, it's listening to.)